# Rectangle display in reputation tab is not same as in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com

There is a minor display issue in the [StackExchange.com - reputation](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) tab with the browsers.

In Google Chrome, there is a rectangle around the charts, but in Mozilla Firefox there is no rectangle displayed.

After inspect the element the following `<rect` tag under the `<svg` caused the issue:

```
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="#FDFDFD" x="0" y="0" width="963" height="400" stroke-width="0.000001" stroke="#4572A7"></rect>
```

The same kind of issue is already discussed in SO [SVG rect not showing up in firefox but works on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45765669/2451726)

It seems the recent design change impacted the rectangle display.

Google Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

> [image: Google Chrome]

Mozilla Firefox 64.0 (64-bit)

> [image: Mozilla Firefox]

---

**UPDATE:** The rectangle display issue is in the User's [Activity tab -> reputation -> graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation&sort=graph) view also.

Comment: The rectangle also doesn't show in Edge.

Comment: The [SVG rect not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45765669/2451726) issue is not applicable here as the rect has width and height attributes.